# In LXE_MASTER, how to choose a specific "Class" when creating a new Object list?

Tags: sap-basis

I want to create a new object list in transaction code **`lxe_master`**, but I want to have **only text elements of a specific class** in my new object list. Is there any way that I can **choose my specific class**? If yes, how can I choose?

I actually created a new object list in `lxe_master` but I could only choose the Paket not the class! After naming the object list, I should choose "Collection" (means Paket) and "Object types". I chose right Paket, imagine that, if there are 4 Classes named (Class1/Class2/Class3/Class4) for example in this Paket and I want to have text elements from **only CLASS 1**, how can I choose this specific class during creation of my new object list?